# How to use props inside the same vue component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a vue Modal component where I define an prop with one array inside, which I want to later on pass to another component from which the modal is open. But when I try to access the prop inside my modal component I am getting the error it is undefined. I could not fix it eventhough the prop is recognized inside my code later it is undefined. Could someone take a look at my code?

script:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "AddGroupsModal",

  data : ()=>({
    model : [],
}),
  props:{
    newGroup: []
  },


methods: {

  generateGroup(){
     const newMeeting = {meetingUrl: "", meetingName: "", date: this.selectedDate, 
      startTime: "", endTime: ""};
    let finalMeetingArray = [];

    this.model.forEach((model, i) => {
      const key = `participant${i + 1}`;
      newMeeting[key] = model.voterUniqueName;
      newMeeting.startTime = model.startTime;
      newMeeting.endTime = model.endTime
    })
    finalMeetingArray.push(newMeeting)
    this.newGroup.push(newMeeting)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.newGroup)
  }

}
}

</script>
```

Comment: How are you passing the prop to the component when you call it?

Comment: Right now I am not passing it at all, just trying to fill it in the component where the prop is defined. Do I have to pass it so it is not undefined?

Comment: My problem right now is not passing it but the component where the prop is defined saying it is undefined

Comment: You are accessing the prop in the correct way but there is nothing inside that prop, that's why it says it is undefined. `undefined` is the JS way of telling you that this variable has no value. You either need to set a default value for this prop or pass something to it.

Comment: But I am trying to push something inside it? Wouldnt that fill it with value. The exact error message is: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: You need an empty array to push into it, set empty array `[]` as a default value for your prop then push.

Comment: I can add another answer if you want to tell you how to do that.

Comment: props:{
    newGroup: []
  },
Isnt this what you told me with setting empty array?

Comment: no, this is not the way to do it, it should be: `props: { newGroup: { type: Array, default: [] } }`

Comment: hey it worked after I put this in my method: this.newGroup = []. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hey @HaithamAlathamneh just a quick question: if I use my method generateGroups() posted in the question I am getting this warning:

Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "newGroup". What does this mean?

Comment: It means that in Vuejs the props are one-way-down, meaning you shouldn't change the value of a prop. If you want a value to use inside the component only, then it should be in `data` not a `prop`. Props are meant to pass values from outside the component, not to update them. Check: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow

Comment: But What I want to do  is fill an array after opening it in my modal. And while closing it I want to pass the value inside those array to another component and display it there. Isnt this the right place to use a prop?

Comment: If you mean to pass data from the modal to its parent, then no! props is not the way to do it. Props are used to pass data from parent to children components. You should use events. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: I am pretty much new to vue, I read the documentation but could not understand it. Could you give me an example maybe? And sorry for the late reply work was a bit much

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify props inside the component. Assuming the prop is called model instead of newGroup, your JS would work

```js
export default {
  name: "AddGroupsModal",

  data : ()=>({
    newGroup : [],
}),
  props:{
    model: []
  },


methods: {

  generateGroup(){
     const newMeeting = {meetingUrl: "", meetingName: "", date: this.selectedDate, 
      startTime: "", endTime: ""};
    let finalMeetingArray = [];

    this.model.forEach((model, i) => {
      const key = `participant${i + 1}`;
      newMeeting[key] = model.voterUniqueName;
      newMeeting.startTime = model.startTime;
      newMeeting.endTime = model.endTime
    })
    finalMeetingArray.push(newMeeting)
    this.newGroup.push(newMeeting)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.newGroup)
  }

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are passing the prop in kebab-case not in camelCase.

If your prop is `newGroup` you should pass it like:

```html
<template>
   <add-groups-modal :new-group="[ ... ]" />
</template>
```

Comment: This [applies only](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case) to in-DOM templates...

Comment: @MichalLevý Yes you are right, thanks. However, there was no enough information in thee question, I had to start somewhere.